# Como recuperar uma imagem base64 com angular no servidor

Tags: angularjs

Eu tenho uma aplicação onde o usuário escolhe uma imagem e salva como

***base64*** no banco. O problema é quando eu retorno a imagem ela não é carregada corretamente.

*Controller:*

```
angular.module("modaFeminina").controller("ProdutoController", function ($scope, $http, $base64) {

$scope.produto = {};

$scope.submeter = function () {

    $scope.produto.Imagem = $base64.encode($scope.produto.Imagem);

    $http.post("/Produto/Salvar", $scope.produto).success(function () {

    }).error(function () {

    });
}
    $scope.Listar = function() {
        $http.get("/Produto/ListarPorId/1", $scope.produto.Id).success(function (produto) {
            $scope.produto = produto;
            $scope.produto.Imagem = $base64.decode(produto.Imagem);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }

});
```

*View*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 ">
        <h4>Cadastrar Produto</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="" name="formulario">
        <div class="col s8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">local_offer</i>
                    <input id="inputProduto" type="text" class="validate" name="Produto" ng-model="produto.NomeProduto">
                    <label for="inputProduto">Produto</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">store</i>
                    <input id="inputLoja" type="text" class="validate" name="Loja" ng-model="produto.Loja">
                    <label for="inputLoja">Loja</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">local_offer</i>
                    <textarea id="textareaDescricao" class="materialize-textarea" ng-model="produto.Descricao"></textarea>
                    <label for="textareaDescricao">Descrição</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">local_offer</i>
                    <input id="inputMarca" type="text" class="validate" name="Marca" ng-model="produto.Marca">
                    <label for="inputMarca">Marca</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">loyalty</i>
                    <input id="inputTipo" type="text" class="validate" name="Tipo" ng-model="produto.Tipo">
                    <label for="inputTipo">Tipo</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4 m4 l4">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">local_offer</i>
                    <input id="inputQuantidade" type="number" class="validate" name="Quantidade" ng-model="produto.Quantidade">
                    <label for="inputQuantidade">Quantidade</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4 m4 l4">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">monetization_on</i>
                    <input id="inputValorPago" type="text" class="validate" name="ValorPago" ng-model="produto.ValorPago">
                    <label for="inputValorPago">Valor Pago</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4 m4 l4">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">monetization_on</i>
                    <input id="inputValorUnitario" type="text" class="validate" name="ValorUnitario" ng-model="produto.ValorUnitario">
                    <label for="inputValorUnitario">Valor Unitário</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="file-field input-field">
                    <div class="btn">
                        <span>File</span>
                        <input type="file">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" ng-model="produto.Imagem">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
            <div class="card small">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" data-ng-src="{{produto.Imagem}}">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{{produto.NomeProduto}}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{{produto.NomeProduto}}<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>{{produto.Descricao}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" ng-click="submeter()" onclick="Materialize.toast('Produto salvo com sucesso!', 4000)" name="action">
                    Salvar
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="Listar()">
                    Voltar
                    <i class="material-icons right">undo</i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Veja se pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235246/angularjs-display-base64-image

Comment: Você também pode criar uma diretiva que lê o arquivo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a imagem, quando codificada para base64, possui um prefixo antes da sequência de caracteres que servem como metadados no seguinte formato:

"data:mimetype;base64,caracteres" onde:

"data:mimetype" corresponde ao tipo de imagem, ex: "data:image/png", "data:image/jpeg", etc
"base64,caracteres" corresponde a string de caracteres que você citou no seu exemplo, mas acrescida do prefixo "base64,"

Com isso, seu exemplo ficaria assim (se fosse uma imagem jpg):

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQMBAAU..."
```

Observe que depois de "base64" colocamos uma vírgula e não dois pontos.

Teste isso usando este [site](https://www.base64-image.de/) onde você faz o upload de uma imagem e ele te dá a respectiva string já em formato base64.